# Left column overflows into and past footer

Tags: html, css

I have a left column, kept to the left inside a container div with the following style:

```
.left-column {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 30vw;    
    border-right: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

I also have a footer at the bottom of the page, pushed to the bottom using the footer push method:

```
.footerWrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -155px;
}

.footer, .footerPush {
    height: 155px;
    @media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    height: 390px;
    }
```

}

When the text contents of the left column flow past the height of the page, instead of pushing the footer down and needing to scroll down, it simply overflows onto and past the footer.

How can I fix this so the content in the left column pushes the footer down?

Edit: HTML of the left column:

```
<div class="belowHeader">
<div class="container whitebg profileMain">
<div class="left-column">
...
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

HTML of footer:

```
<div class="footerPush"></div>
<footer>
....
</footer>
```

CSS of belowHeader:

```
.belowHeader {
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    padding-top: 233px;
    }
    padding-top: 103px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Could you share HTML ?

Comment: Added the HTML and more CSS

Comment: It can't push anything anywhere on the page, because it is out of low, its position is `absolute`.

Comment: Is there any middle point? To keep it absolute with respect to the parent div but otherwise within the flow of the page

Comment: @edd91 Please can you provide a reproducible example in a Stack snippet.